# PhantomJS CustomHeader causes Error

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, custom-headers

Adding a Custom Header seems to fail for this site, in Script 2, I have just commented out the "Accept" custom header and it works. Any ideas? Phantom Only provides a value "Syntax Error Parse Error" response. Also the error shows up multiple times as if each line has an error.

SCRIPT 1 - Does Not Work

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
var fs = require('fs');

page.settings.userAgent='Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.114 Safari/537.36';

page.onInitialized = function() {
  page.customHeaders = {
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.114 Safari/537.36",
         "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8",
         "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.8"
      };
page.viewportSize = {width: 1280, height: 1024};
};

    page.evaluate(function(){
    });


page.open('http://www.gleanster.com/', function (status) {
    if(status =='success'){
    }

    page.render('export.png');
    fs.write('1.html', page.content, 'w');
    phantom.exit();
});
```

SCRIPT 2 - works

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
var fs = require('fs');

page.settings.userAgent='Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.114 Safari/537.36';

page.onInitialized = function() {
  page.customHeaders = {
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.114 Safari/537.36",
   //      "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8",
         "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.8"
      };
page.viewportSize = {width: 1280, height: 1024};
};

    page.evaluate(function(){
    });


page.open('http://www.gleanster.com/', function (status) {
    if(status =='success'){
    }

    page.render('export.png');
    fs.write('1.html', page.content, 'w');
    phantom.exit();
});
```

Comment: That is quite a complicated Accept header, so have you tried other simpler ones? E.g. try just `"Accept":"text/html"`, and then work your way up from there, until it breaks. (I wondered if `+` or `=` might need escaping, but as far as I can tell any printable ASCII character is allowed in an HTTP header value.)